# IOS how make iCarousel scroll like UIScrollView page

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, icarousel

i want use iCarouse to implement scroll by page that is like UIScrollView paged

iCarouse code://it is not work

```
carousel.delegate = self;
carousel.dataSource = self;
carousel.scrollSpeed = 0.8f;
//carousel.wrapEnabled = YES;
carousel.stopAtItemBoundary = YES;
carousel.scrollToItemBoundary = YES;
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow;
```

scroll code:

```
[scrollView setPagingEnable:YES];//I want to achieve this
```

Comment: @mstfbsnli my iCarouse show three item in a page,when i scroll the iCarouse ,it is Continuous rolling more than one item.

Comment: have tried all the available types(carousel.type)?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
carousel.decelerationRate = 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `carousel.pagingEnabled = YES;`